# Issue when resizing overlay on Parallax

Tags: html, css, parallax.js

I just bought [this template](http://demo.tempload.com/jirono/blue-index.html).
When resizing the window under 991px, the overlay does not fit the section because of padding 60px. Do you know what I can do to resolve this ?
[image]

Comment: Share your code please

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="parallax-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="info">
                    <p>We design and develop <span>web apps</span> that delight your users and grow your business.</p>
                    <a class="btn-white-line" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parallax {
min-height: 215px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
padding-top: 60px;
padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.parallax:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 140%;
height: 140%;
opacity: .80;
background: #585CE9;
z-index: 2;
top: -20%;
left: -20%;
}

.parallax .parallax-content {
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .parallax {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 60px;
        min-height: auto;
    }
}
```